# Gravity Forms form's first page footer is overlying the actual form

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, layout, gravity-forms-plugin

I have strange problem with multipage form - the problem occurs only on first page of the form: http://www.cledu.ca/disc-jockey-coverage/#_form_1

If you debug the gform_page_footer element you'll see that it is overlying the whole form and therefore the bottom line is at top and the "next" button is moved up. Please tell me what more info do you need in order to solve this issue.

Comment: it seems to be like that when I am using gf_right_half and gf_left_half classes. Do they have any special requirements?

Comment: anybody? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add overflow:hidden to .gform_wrapper ul.gform_fields and it will fix the issue - [Screenshot](http://grab.by/EhSc)

Comment: Actually it helped, but now footer overlies the "Coverage Length" select. Click it and you'll see. How to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how much this helps but the issue is connected to your use of relative and absolute positioning on the select itself. Once I removed these from the element, the drop-down showed up fine. http://grab.by/EzOA